# webgl - trying to create my first tiny square box

Tags: javascript, canvas, webgl

I am very new to webGL and was trying to get one simple square box to appear in my canvas using javascript. I do not know how to debug. It would be great if somebody could help me. Thanks!

```js
    var gl,
        shaderProgram;
    initGL();
    createShaders();
    draw();
    
    function initGL() { 
      let canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
      gl = canvas.getContext("webgl");
      gl.viewport(0.0, 0.0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
      gl.clearColor(0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);  // colors for r, g, b and alpha. these are all normalized values from 0 to 1.
    }
    
    function createShaders(){
      var vs="";
      vs+="void main(void) {";
      vs+="  gl_Position = vec4(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0)";
      vs+="  gl_PointSize = 10.0;";
      vs+="}";
      
      
      var vertexShader = gl.createShader(gl.VERTEX_SHADER);
      gl.shaderSource(vertexShader, vs);
      gl.compileShader(vertexShader);
      
      var fs="";
      fs+="void main(void) {";
      fs+="  gl_FragColor = vec4(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0)"; // Fully opaque black
      fs+="}";
      
      var fragmentShader = gl.createShader(gl.FRAGMENT_SHADER);
      gl.shaderSource(fragmentShader, fs);
      gl.compileShader(fragmentShader);
      
      shaderProgram = gl.createProgram();
      gl.attachShader(shaderProgram, vertexShader);
      gl.attachShader(shaderProgram, fragmentShader);
      gl.linkProgram(shaderProgram);
      gl.useProgram(shaderProgram);
      
    }
    
    function draw(){ 
      gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
      gl.drawArrays(gl.POINTS, 0, 1);
    }
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="600" height="600"> </canvas>
```

Comment: Why you don't start with `three.js` to understand the concept first.

Comment: thanks @pirs but based on discussions with a lot of engineers, I think understanding the nitty gritty of the library, understanding what exactly goes into building the structures will better train me, so I will be less clueless with my Three.js errors- I guess this initial pain is inevitable :)

Comment: A good source you can start with is [**MDN docs**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebGL_API/Tutorial/Creating_3D_objects_using_WebGL)

Comment: Ok, as you want, i think `three.js` team took care about the names of functions and their meanings, that why it should be a good way to learn. Else, you ll need to learn OpenGL : https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/

Comment: **OpenGL is not WebGL**, its not even close, if anything then its OpenGL ES  2.0 for WebGL 1 and OpenGL ES 3.0 for WebGL 2.

Comment: you might find [these tutorials](https://webglfundamentals.com) helpful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please read some [different tutorials on WebGL](https://webglfundmentals.org)

The issue is you're getting a shader compiler error. If you open the JavaScript Console you'd likely see

[image]

That first message means your shader program is bad

Whatever book/site you were reading should have told you to check for shader compilation errors like this

```
      { 
        const success = gl.getShaderParameter(vertexShader, gl.COMPILE_STATUS);
        if (!success) {
           console.error(gl.getShaderInfoLog(vertexShader));
           return false;
        }
      }
```

And also for program link errors like this

```
      { 
        const success = gl.getProgramParameter(shaderProgram, gl.LINK_STATUS);
        if (!success) {
           console.error(gl.getProgramInfoLog(shaderProgram));
           return false;
        }
      }
```

That would have pointed out something is wrong with your shaders. You were missing a semicolon on this line

```
      gl_Position = vec4(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0)
```

Please read some better tutorials. Also consider using JavaScript [multiline template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals). Much easier than concatenating strings.

Also calling `gl.useProgram` inside a function that compiles and links shaders is an anti-pattern. WebGL applications usually have more than one shader program.

```js
var gl,
        shaderProgram;
    initGL();
    createShaders();
    draw();
    
    function initGL() { 
      let canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
      gl = canvas.getContext("webgl");
      gl.viewport(0.0, 0.0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
      gl.clearColor(0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);  // colors for r, g, b and alpha. these are all normalized values from 0 to 1.
    }
    
    function createShaders(){
      var vs=`
      void main(void) {
        gl_Position = vec4(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
        gl_PointSize = 10.0;
      }`;
      
      var vertexShader = gl.createShader(gl.VERTEX_SHADER);
      gl.shaderSource(vertexShader, vs);
      gl.compileShader(vertexShader);
      { 
        const success = gl.getShaderParameter(vertexShader, gl.COMPILE_STATUS);
        if (!success) {
           console.error(gl.getShaderInfoLog(vertexShader));
           return false;
        }
      }
      
      
      var fs=`
      void main(void) {
        gl_FragColor = vec4(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0); // Fully opaque black
      }`;
      
      var fragmentShader = gl.createShader(gl.FRAGMENT_SHADER);
      gl.shaderSource(fragmentShader, fs);
      gl.compileShader(fragmentShader);
      { 
        const success = gl.getShaderParameter(fragmentShader, gl.COMPILE_STATUS);
        if (!success) {
           console.error(gl.getShaderInfoLog(fragmentShader));
           return false;
        }
      }
      
      shaderProgram = gl.createProgram();
      gl.attachShader(shaderProgram, vertexShader);
      gl.attachShader(shaderProgram, fragmentShader);
      gl.linkProgram(shaderProgram);
      { 
        const success = gl.getProgramParameter(shaderProgram, gl.LINK_STATUS);
        if (!success) {
           console.error(gl.getProgramInfoLog(shaderProgram));
           return false;
        }
      }      
      
      gl.useProgram(shaderProgram);
      return true;   // this is bad. You should be returning the program
    }
    
    function draw(){ 
      gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
      gl.drawArrays(gl.POINTS, 0, 1);
    }
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="600" height="600"> </canvas>
```

Comment: I'm curious is there any spec backing up this behavior when drawing without setting up, binding and ultimately using any vertex attributes? [The spec states](https://www.khronos.org/registry/webgl/specs/latest/1.0/#6.6) *"If a vertex attribute is enabled as an array via enableVertexAttribArray but no buffer is bound to that attribute via bindBuffer and vertexAttribPointer, then calls to drawArrays or drawElements will generate an INVALID_OPERATION error."* and iirc attrib 0 is enabled by default isn't it?

Comment: @LJ, no attributes are enabled by default. By the way [vertexshaderart.com](https://www.vertexshaderart.com) is kind of dedicated to the idea of no attributes. Unfortunately there's no useful data in WebGL1 with no attributes but [there is in WebGL2](http://jsfiddle.net/greggman/jrz9dqyd/)